# React-native run-android fail on :app:processDebugResources

Tags: android, react-native

I recently added push notification to my app using [react-native](https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android%20module)
and since at seemingly random times I get messages such as in the added photo
Execution failed for task

```
':app:processDebugResources'.
 java.io.IOException: Could not delete folder ..\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\facebook\drawee
```

[image: the error message]

Did anyone experienced something like that or has a solution?

Comment: Incase anyone else reach here as I did check following http://stackoverflow.com/a/42707592/4221558

Answer (score 17):

Run this command to clean project:

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

After, run the following command to run project again:

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Comment: Such a lifesaver! I had this problem for like two months and never solved. Instead i would just keep rebuilding and waiting! The most recent time came out to 45min and it still didnt work and I finally found this. The top answer that always came up for me in the past was this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45222227/1828637 - but it was so useless. Thank you so much! Also a note, for me `gradlew clean` didnt work I had to do `.\gradlew clean`, I'm on Win10.

Comment: @Noitidart it's pleasure to help u :D

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I changed the permissions of the project folder and all subfolders to full access from all users, and now it seems to work!

Comment: If you are in Windows - you might want to run powershell with admin rights ... i forgot that and lost 30 minutes of stupid staring at the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the packager can cause two types of file-access errors to occur during gradle syncing and building:

1) "EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat"

2) "java.io.IOException: Could not delete path"

These are actually two separate problems -- one of them caused by the watchman npm module, and the other caused by the packager itself.

Instructions to solve them can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420765/2441655

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application in android device then go to the android director in your react native project then `Delete` the build folder/(Directory) then again run the project.Its work for me

The path of the build folder

> YourProject/android/