# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > java.io.IOException: Could not delete folder "" in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to develop a Android application using Android Studio,
so I created an Android app and I want to publish it.
Whenever I click on “build project“ to obtain the apk file,
I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete folder C:\Users\ehsan\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\ehsan
```

[image: Screenshot showing the error message]

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ehsan.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: paste your gradle file..

Comment: @cgr which one build or setting?

Comment: paste the build gradle.

Comment: Hi , exec this code root project `gradlew --stacktrace ` . May help you.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568314/5305430. lifetime solution of problem.

Comment: I found this solution useful for me [Answer to -> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55156193/11618893)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I guess some of the files in the target build directory is open in another tool you use. Just a file handle open in the folder which has to be cleaned. The build task 'clean' wants to delete all the files in the build directory(normally 'target') and when it fails, the build fails.

Comment: I just remove the folder and build again.

Comment: Hi..what folder should I remove ?

Comment: If using **React Native**, inside the project folder there will be `android`, remove `build` from there - at least that's what worked for me.

Comment: @Henning Luther Is any other solution for this because my project is large every time clean and build takes 25 minutes

Comment: @Rose try to split your project into smaller modules where not all is rebuild all the time but only changed modules

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568314/5305430. lifetime solution of problem.

Comment: I am just bored hitting the run button multiple times.

Answer (score 180):

## REACT NATIVE

From your react native folder run:

`cd android && gradlew clean`

THEN

`cd .. && react-native run-android`

> *Notes:*
>
> For mac you may need to change `gradlew` to `./gradlew`
>
> For the command prompt you may need to change the `&&` to `&`
>
> For powershell you may need to change the `&&` to `;` and `gradlew` to `.\gradlew.bat`
>
> Each command can also be run individually like so `cd android` then `gradlew clean` then `cd ..` then `react-native run-android`

Comment: `cd android && gradlew clean` clean didn't work, but `cd android` then `gradlew clean` worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: This works, but makes the build process much slower... Wish there were a way to solve the root problem!

Comment: Finally found a way which seems to solve the root problem! https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9136#issuecomment-306131670

Comment: fyi, for Windows, you'll need to use `gradlew.bat`.

Comment: In windows, gradlew.bat clean worked for me but these days this problem happened to me several times and I don't know what the reason is!

Answer (score 21):

Just clean your project, it works for me.

Clean task for gradle will work.

Comment: exactly the clean is not working, as you can see in the ops question, of course a later clean can solve it just because the file handle got closed by os

Comment: a better solution is to run:`cd android && ./gradlew clean` as mentioned by @robertmylne

Answer (score 9):

Fix This issue by this command

In Windows Platform

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd..
```

In Mac Platform

> `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`

Answer (score 5):

Fix is very simple: Just follow below instructions

1. First, save the project
2. Click on project folder
3. Click on Syncronize button in the menubar (The third icon from the left which is just below to File menu option)
4. Clean project and run

Answer (score 5):

as others have said allready you need to clean your project , the steps to clean the project are:

Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: this worked for me, except I also had to delete the (empty) 'build' folder in windows explorer since AS seemed unable to. Clean then worked OK.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, that problem is about permissions. if you open android studio as administrator (or using sudo) then if you open the project again as normal user, android studio may not delete some files because when you open the project as administrator, some project files permissions are changed. If you lived those steps, I think you should clone the project from your VCS (git, tfs, svn etc.) again. Otherwise you have to configure project file - folder permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue. When I clean my project and rebuild it then everything works fine.

Build -> Clean Project

Answer (score 2):

Just clean your project (Android Studio>Build>Clean Project) and build again.

Answer (score 2):

I found another handy solution, which avoids rebuilding all components again and again, in this article:
http://bitstopixels.blogspot.ca/2017/04/react-native-windows-10-eperm-operation.html

1. Execute `react-native run-android`
2. As soon as React Packager window opens, close it
3. Wait for `react-native run-android` to complete giving you the BUILD SUCCESSFUL message. (The app will be launched with a red error screen complaining connecting to server failed. Don't panic.)
4. Then run `react-native start` to start the React Packager, this is the server indicated in the error message of the previous step
5. Reload the app in emulator or device (Double tap the R key)

Answer (score 2):

If you encountered these errors due to opening the android studio with sudo command, then the solution is setting permission for the project folder.
Run the command below.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 your_project_folder
```

clean and rebuild again your android project.

Answer (score 1):

**React Native**

These steps solved my problem:

- Renaming of ReactNativeApp/android/build directory to old.build
- Closing Android Studio
- Inside ReactNativeApp/android executed this command. 
     gradlew clean
- Making sure my RAM is 1500mb free
- Then finally executing the command
     react-native run-android

** It's quite interesting to close Android Studio. But beleive me these steps solved my problem **

Answer (score 1):

Stopping OpenSdk Java process (inner to Android Studio process) worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another instance of Android Studio running, then kindly close it and then build the app. This worked in my case

Answer (score 1):

If you are using macOS then => `sudo ./gradlew clean` will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted folder app/build and the problem was resolved in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**Update your gradle version.**

Go to your project level `build.gradle` file and make sure you are using the latest version of gradle.

Answer (score 0):

### React Native

In my case I just refresh ( http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ ) , and it works... Any other solutions didn't work for me. Perhaps some files are used by debuger and it can't delete them... Anyway, it works for me. Please try this and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If it says:

> *The term 'gradlew' is not recognized*

Then using following command

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

worked for me. cheers!

Comment: I don't really see how this answer is related to the question. OP did not say anything about this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Delete android/app/build folder and run `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in React Native, you can also restart your CLI and this error goes away.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21915675)

Comment: I hope you added a comment to the other 5 similar posts in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on windows 10 and i can't find gradlew  i cleaned the project using Android Studio : 
 Build ---> clean project and after that i was able to run :
react-native run-android or to run project using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

i just delete the error package from package.json and run again gradlew clean and its works for me *For React Native*

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that you had the app installed and when you gave it `react-native run-android` I could not install the app since it was already previously installed

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your text editor (maybe VS Code) and File Explorer and run the command again in terminal with admin permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Just Do onething File->Invalidate caches/ restart.
After loading the project sync the project.[image]