# react-native run-android Building Error ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'

Tags: java, android, react-native, build

I am having a problem to build a new project. I am using React-Native and Android Emulator (AVD) but when I use the command `react-native run-android` I get the following message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\diego\Desktop\Diego\albums\android\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com'.
>
> * Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2 mins 47.189 secs
>
> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Here's an image of the prompt: [Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p460b.png)

How can I fix this?

-------------------------------------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------------------------

I added the value `C:\....\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` to the variable `Path` and I got build sucessful. Problem solved. Yay.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read about react native documentation? I think that's pretty obvious, if you've followed the steps of this documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html then there's a possibility that there's an error configuring Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable i hope this answer can help you :)

Comment: Actually the problem was in the variable Path. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Helped a lot.

Comment: First try 'cd android && gradlew clean'

Comment: This solution solved my problem... [Answer to--> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57323506/11618893)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@diego-barreto

Added the value `C:\....\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` to the variable `Path` and I got build sucessful. Problem solved. Yay.

Answer (score 6):

cd android //Navigate into the android folder from the root directory

gradlew clean // Run this

Comment: Related, see https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/402

Answer (score 2):

Create `rn.sh` file in your root of React native project with following content

```
 cd android/app/
 rm -rf build
 cd ..
 cd ..
react-native run-android
```

Then run from terminal or cmd

```
./rn.sh
```

Recommendation

VSCode must be run as Admistrator
or [GitDesktop](https://desktop.github.com/)
must be run as Administrator

Answer (score 1):

**React Native**

Faced similar issue while building react native app. Running on the different port as the default port (8081) is used by some other app.

Command to build the app.

`react-native run-android --port=8082`

**Solution**
My case

(Removed extra attribute `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. If you check the log, it says

> lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 56; Attribute "screenOrientation" bound
>   to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already
>   specified for element "activity".

hence removed the same attribute. This was being added multiple times

**Error log**

```
Configure project :react-native-webview
:react-native-webview:reactNativeAndroidRoot /Users/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/react-native/android

Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/PROJECT_PATH/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 56; Attribute "screenOrientation" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "activity".

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
32 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 31 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
```

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: This help me but I don't understand why the error message is confusing with the fact that it has nothing to do with android but react server.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate into the android folder of your react-native project and type the following:

gradlew cleanBuildCache

Then fire up something like Android Studio do a build and you should find the issue is resolved.  If you still get errors check the log carefully the information is in there just hard to find.