# React Native : Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to implement React Native `MapView` for Android. I did follow [github installation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md) instruction but i am facing compilation error when i try to run using `react-native run-android` command.

> > Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-maps:debugCompileClasspath'.
>     Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0.
>     Required by:
>       project :react-native-maps
>     Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-compat' that satisfies the version constraints:
>         Dependency path 'MapViewDemo:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' -
>     -> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
>         Dependency path 'MapViewDemo:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' -
>     -> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
>         Dependency path 'MapViewDemo:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' -
>     -> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
>         Dependency path 'MapViewDemo:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' -
>     -> 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
>         Dependency path 'MapViewDemo:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-serv
>     ices-basement:16.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
>         Dependency path 'MapViewDemo:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' -
>     -> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
>        'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following rea
>     son: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
>         Constraint path 'MapViewDemo:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following rea
>     son: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug

**App level gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
*/
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mapviewdemo"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86-64"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86-64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-maps')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'


}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
 }

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
}
```

**Project level gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 20
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MapViewDemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.0",
"react-native-maps": "^0.23.0"
},
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.3.4",
  "@babel/runtime": "7.3.4",
  "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
  "jest": "24.5.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
 },
  "jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After two day's of struggling i find my solution by my self.The real issue is my project using `compileSdkVersion = 28` and `react-native-maps` node_module using different version of `compileSdkVersion`.

To solve this issue need to update `react-native-maps` node_module `compileSdkVersion` version.

project_name>node_modules>react-native-maps>lib>android>build.gradle

```
 ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 20
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

**Module compile SDK version and support library version should be same as project compile SDK version and support library version.**

Answer (score 0):

this also worked for me.

Modify android/build.gradle as follows

1) Add google() inside repositories

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // add google() here
        google()
```

2) Update com.android.tools.build.gradle to 3.1.0

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
      // update from 2.2.3 to 3.1.0 
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

3) Add google() inside repositories after dependencies :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
    allprojects {
      repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        // add googgle() here
        google()
```

4) Add `android.enableAapt2=false` to android/gradle.properties

```
android.enableAapt2=false // < ---  add here
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
```

5) Update gradle version in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
// from version 2.14.1

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

// change to 4.10.1

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

6) Run `react-native run-android`

Comment: I did follow your instruction but still showing error `> Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.
`

Comment: in my app level gradle i have not inserted following lines.

`implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}`

Answer (score 0):

did you able to make it work ?. i found another solution. in my case, this happens because of the version of react-native (0.59.0). so i change my react-native version in my package.json file form `0.59.0` to `^0.58.6`. and the react-native-maps version to `^0.23.0`. here are the other steps.

1) in app level settings.gradle, include this

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

2) in project level gradle, remove or comment

```
    ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 20
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

(inside buildscript{})

3) also in project level gradle,
change the classpath. build.gradle version to 3.1.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
```

also add another url inside maven{} (inside allprojects{})

```
maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
```

4) now change app level gradle as follows

first, change compileSdkVersion to 28 and add new buildToolVersion

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

then, change min and target SdkVersion as follows (inside defaultConfig)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mapviewdemo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

5) in your AndroidManifest.xml,

first add this code. this is to give permission to access location on your device. add this before `<aplication>` tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

then you have to add your meta-data before `</application>` tag.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBTSDBtI7_dfdfBeYkNAtdQ8sT67HiOuO0VU"/>
```

(add your own API key for `android:value`)

6) then run `npm install` and try whether this working or not. if this isn't working, you have to download Android SDK from android studio. in my case, i downloaded Android 7.0 and 6.0

Comment: Yes i able to make it work. 
Your solution is also correct but i think rather then downgrading project `react-native` version upgrade `react-native-maps` version is better solution.

Comment: glad to hear that. so what is the new `react-native-maps` version in your project?

Comment: I did upgrade `react-native` version of `react-native-maps` which is 0.59.0.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem using this npm install — save “react-native-maps@jerolimov/react-native-maps#fix-rn59rc-compile-issues”

from: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/pull/2702

the problem is with React native 0.59+ that compile with compileSdkVersion 28 and maps use 26

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days I found the problem in my project.
I changed the values of **compileSdkVersion**, **supportLibVersion** and **playServicesVersion** in
  `android/build.gradle`  and  `android/app/build.gradle`  files to the same values as in `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle`  and  `node_modules/react-native-maps/build.gradle` files, this worked for me.

Values of **compileSdkVersion**, **supportLibVersion** and **playServicesVersion** are same in all the below files.

> in **android/build.gradle** file:

```
...
ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 28
    targetSdkVersion    = 27
    buildToolsVersion   = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion       = 16
    supportLibVersion   = "28.0.0"
    playServicesVersion = "16.1.0" // or set latest version
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
...
```

> in **android/app/build.gradle** file:

```
...
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.reactnativeapp2"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
...
...
}
...
dependencies {
   ...
   ...
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}
...
```

> in **node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle** file:

```
...
android {
  compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 28)

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 16)
    targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 27)
  }
}


dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '28.0.0')}"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${safeExtGet('playServicesVersion', '16.1.0')}"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${safeExtGet('playServicesVersion', '16.1.0')}"
  implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
}
...
```

> in **node_modules/react-native-maps/build.gradle** file:

```
...
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
    playServicesVersion = '16.1.0'
  }
...
```