# react-native not working genymotion on ubuntu

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, genymotion

ı am beginer react native developer ı trying show me react native project on genymotion but ı cant do.

```
react-native run-android
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC9BW.png)

ı had error in terminal

Total time: 5.993 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: enable usb debugging

Comment: check if the emulator is listed with adb devices

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to clean project:

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

After, run the following command to run project again:

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951825/8753942)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved by this,

1) Install watchman from [here](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html).

but installing watchman requires other dependencies and throws errors, install them one by one without missing any.

2) Go to your project folder from where you run commands as react-native run-android,

3) run following commands or puth this commands in one file and save with extension `.sh` e.g. `filename.sh`.

```
touch .watchmanconfig
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
sudo pkill -9 -x fseventsd
echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_queued_events=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

even if this doesn't help, then install expo client in real-android phone,
and run.